# Retrivie VideoID

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have two classes (YtAdapter and MainActivity).
In YtAdapter I have a method that gets user input (keyword) and search for Youtube videos for that keyword.
It is done right and working good.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mHolder;
    if(convertView != null){
        mHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }else{
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_item,null);
        mHolder.mVideoThumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
        mHolder.mVideoTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    }
    //Setting the data
    SearchResult result = mVideoList.get(position);
    mHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(result.getSnippet().getTitle());

    //Loading the image
    Picasso.with(mActivity).load(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()).into(mHolder.mVideoThumbnail);

    return  convertView;
}
```

The only problem is that I can see the videos but not play them.
In my MainActivity I have an OnItemClicked method that should play the video, however, I can't understand how to retrive the VideoID (string) of one of the videos in the list.

Could anyone help me get this done?
This is the code of the OnItemClicked method:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    VIDEO_ID = <<<<------ I need to get the VideoID of the video im clicking on in the list of the videos.
    Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this,AppConstants.KEY,VIDEO_ID); /*Needed: result.getSnippet().get(videoID());*/
    startActivity(videoIntent);
}
```

I thought about a String variable in the YtAdpater and use that variable in the MainActivity, working on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the clicked videoId like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    VIDEO_ID = searchResult.getId().getVideoId();
    Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this,AppConstants.KEY,VIDEO_ID); /*Needed: result.getSnippet().get(videoID());*/
    startActivity(videoIntent);
}
```